# Control transmitter operation

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, current, amplifier

[image]

So I'm new to servomechanisms and am initially unclear on 2 things.

1. For a control transmitter, I know that it converts the shaft position to an electrical signal. How exactly does it do that?
2. If this signal were to amplified, how is the control transmitter connected to an op-amp?

Any explanation would be appreciated

Comment: The picture is a separate excited AC generator or motor. So what kind of position sensor you have in mind? There are plenty: resolver, selsyn, synchro, quadrature encoder, ...

Comment: By varying the coupling from primary R to secondaries S.

Answer (score 0):

> *For a control transmitter, I know that it converts the shaft position
> to an electrical signal. How exactly does it do that?*

Do you understand 3 phase motors and generators? If you don't then any answer is going to be too lengthy to fit the format for this site. However, [Moog](https://www.moog.com/literature/MCG/synchrohbook.pdf) do a very good pamphlet on them so I would urge you to read it and learn. There is a lot to take in but, in a nutshell: -

[image]

> *If this signal were to amplified, how is the control transmitter
> connected to an op-amp?*

These sort of 3 phase synchro-resolver transmitters are not connected to op-amps; they are usually connected to an identical device via S1, S2 and S3 thus movement of one device causes movement to the connected device and vice versa (this is why you need to understand 3 ph theory). Sometimes the three outputs (S1-3) are connected to ADCs and the angle is derived using an MCU.

I have never seen them used with op-amps because the output voltages don't need amplification.

Comment: @BeatriceUK - if you are done with this question please formally accept an answer else raise a comment for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite rare that the control transformer is connected that way round, that looks more like an alternator.

When used as a control transmitter, a three phase supply goes to the S terminals, and a single phase constant amplitude signal is taken from R terminals. The phase of this signal, with respect to the phase of one of the three exciting phases, represents the angle of the shaft.

When controlling a similar shaft in a servo mechanism, another identical transmitter driven by the same three phase signal is driven by the controlled shaft. The R outputs from each transmitter are taken to a phase sensitive detector, or PSD, whose output is a DC voltage or current representing the phase shift between the two inputs. This goes into a servo loop filter and amplifier, where it's used to drive the controlled shaft, until the phase shift goes to zero.

The same setup can be used without the first control transmitter, using some form of phase measurement for the feedback from the transmitter on the controlled shaft.